# protractor gives {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"} error

Tags: protractor

> I have an issue with 2 elements need to combine and check result with a label string.

```
    firstName = element(by.model("emergencyContactObject.firstName"));
    lastName = element(by.model("emergencyContactObject.lastName"));

    firstName.clear().sendKeys("firstName");
    lastName.clear().sendKeys("lastName");

    firstNameText = firstName.getText().then(function(fnm){
        return fnm;
    });

    browser.wait(firstNameText);

    lastNameText = lastName.getText().then(function(lnm){
        return lnm;
    });

    browser.wait(lastNameText);

    nameText = firstNameText+' '+lastNameText;

    var nameH3 = element(by.css('h3'));

    expect(nameH3.getText()).toBe(nameText);
```

## Protractor gives below error:

> Expected 'frstName lastName' to be 'ManagedPromise::7999 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"} ManagedPromise::8021 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}'

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `browser.wait();` won't resolve your promise and returning from `then` will still return a promise not a result of promise. Unfortunately you have to wrap multiple `then()`, because you have multiple variables.

```
firstName.getText().then(function(fnm){
        lastName.getText().then(function(lnm){
            firstNameText = fnm;
            lastNameText = lnm;
            nameText = firstNameText + ' ' + lastNameText;
            var nameH3 = element(by.css('h3'));

            expect(nameH3.getText()).toBe(nameText);
        });
    });
```

Alternatively, you can make use of `async/await`, but you have to mark your function `async`.

```
 var firstNameText = await firstName.getText();
 var lastNameText = await lastName.getText();
 var nameText = firstNameText + ' ' + lastNameText;  
 var nameH3 = element(by.css('h3'));

 expect(nameH3.getText()).toBe(nameText);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your issue, I believe, is with this part of your code, where you are assigning a promise to the variable "firstNameText" rather than assigning the result of that promise:

```
firstNameText = firstName.getText().then(function(fnm){
    return fnm;
});
```

Try:

```
var firstNameText;    
firstName.getText().then(function(fnm){
    firstNameText = fnm;
});
```